# PHP recursive function - Good manners

Tags: php

With this code:

```
function lookForTheA($str, $pos) {
    if ($str[$pos] == 'A') {
        return 'is in position: '.$pos;
    } else {
        $pos++;
        return lookForTheA($str, $pos);
    }
}

$str = 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA';
$res = lookForTheA($str, 0);
echo $res;
```

I need to know if the second return (line 6) is needed.
If it's a good way to resolve it.

Comment: I'd rather have one return in line 3 and in this line just function call without return.

Comment: why not just removing the return and see how it goes ?

Comment: i think you should remove the second return, add a test if the $pos in your $str exist instead of just else and return null if it out of range

Comment: I think it's not duplicate, The other question explain the recursion and it resolve one of the points, but I want to know if this is a good practice or I can do it in another way too. And yes, I try to remove the second and it doesn't works but I didn't understand well why

Comment: Asking for good practise is off-topic on StackOverflow.